# is it possible to use dynamic types in c# generic methods?

Tags: c#

for example i need something like this:

```
 SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<armour>();
```

armour is a class. but i need to get type of object to send to it in order to avoid rewriting this function.

for example it need:

```
SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<"classType">();
```

or

```
 SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<obj.getType()>();
```

to send the type to generic function. but i always receive that you send a variable not a type to generic function.

what should i really do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small fixed set of types you need to work with, known in advance, you can get around this with a wrapper function that checks the type and selects the appropriate generic method to call:

```
public IEnumerable GetItemsOfType(System.Type type) {
    if(type == typeof(Armour))
        return SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<Armour>();
    if(type == typeof(Weapon))
        return SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<Weapon>();
    // ...

    Assert("Called GetItemsOfType with an unsupported type: " + type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

You can save all the ifs by storing a dictionary of delegates and looking up from that using the type as a key:

```
public delegate IEnumerable ItemGetter();
Dictionary<System.Type, ItemGetter> typedItemGetters;

//...later initialized like so:
typedItemGetters = new Dictionary<System.Type, ItemGetter>{
    {typeof(Armour), SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<Armour>},
    {typeof(Weapon), SQLITE._instance.ds.GetItems<Weapon>},
    //...
};

// And used like so:
public IEnumerable GetItemsOfType(System.Type type) {
    return typedItemGetters[type]();
}
```